# Between operator is not working in JSON datatype - mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-json

I have following `JSON format` in the mysql table `statistics` and the column is `stats`

```
{
  "stats":{
     "cities":[
         {
            "name":"Melbourne",
            "country":"AU",
            "value":0.245
         },
         {
            "name":"London",
            "country":"GB",
            "value":0.56
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

#### What I have Tried: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3bBb3SvnFafzzo3mX68tZ3/0)

```sql
SELECT
  `stats`,
  `a`.`stats` -> '$.stats.cities[*].name'
FROM
  `statistics` `a`
WHERE
  `a`.`stats` -> '$.stats.cities[*].value' BETWEEN 0.1 and 0.4;
```

Above `query` doesn't fetch any rows.

#### Requirement:

I have to fetch **value** `BETWEEN` 0.1 and 0.4

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: @lad2025  Thanks for helping. Not working in this [case](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qB5zceR1vVhJCGMU7j9fSa/1)

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks again, Fails on [0.400 and 0.600](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/46ofEWfPYwT6jBhBpWZFUo/1)

Comment: The problem is that `a.stats -> '$.stats.cities[*].value'` returns a JSON array of all the values, you're not testing the individual values.

Comment: I don't think MySQL has a JSON function that allows you to test conditions on all the values that are returned by an extraction.

Comment: You need to properly normalize your schema, instead of using JSON.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks a lot, Better I will change the schema